# Ayuda con Formateo de numeros en Django 1.9

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

hola tengo el siguiente problema, estoy tratando de formatear números con la ayuda de la librería [jquery-number](https://github.com/customd/jquery-number), el problema es que cuando yo quiero asignarle sus propiedades al input no lo logro ya que al momento de colocar dicho campo de la siguiente manera `{{ form.precio_c }}` y no se como enredarle 
las propiedades de dicha librería para que formatee el numero.

lo e tratado de colocar en div pero no funciona.
o hay otra forma de hacerlo ?

lo que quiero lograr es si coloco un numero 
ejemplo: 12000  que lo formatee de esta manera 12,000.00

saludos..

mi codigo es asi..

```
<div class="input-field col s3 m3" >
  {{ form.precio_c }}
  <label for="last_name">{{ form.precio_c.label }}</label>
</div>
```

propiedades de la librería

```
id="price" name="number"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Las clases y atributos de los elementos de un formulario, si quieres usar el objeto `form` debes colocarlos en la clase que crea el formulario. En tu caso, usa un campo [`form.DecimalField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/forms/fields/#decimalfield) y un *widget* [`NumberInput`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.NumberInput).

```
from .models import Precio
from django import forms

class PrecioForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Precio
        exclude = []

    precio_c = forms.DecimalField(
        widget=forms.NumberInput(
            attrs={'id': 'price', name="number"}
        )
    )
```

Consulta la documentación sobre los [*widgets*](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.Widget.attrs).

Comment: amigo esto lo agrego en el model.py verdad saludos o en mi views.py

Comment: En donde defines tu formulario. Generalmente el archivo se llama `forms.py`.

Comment: no uso forms.py, entonces lo creeare para ese campo

Comment: ` class ProductosCreationView(SuccessMessageMixin, CreateView):
 template_name = 'productos/master.html'
 model = Producto
 success_url = reverse_lazy('registrar_producto')
 success_message = 'Producto %(catalogo_P)s Registrado'
 fields = ('__all__') `                                                                                                                                         **asi es como lo tengo , o se puede que lo coloque en una funcion ?  **

Comment: En los comentarios no puedes pegar texto. Te recomiendo que edites tu pregunta si lo que necesitas es ampliar la información.